# How to rename a bluetooth device in OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, settings

Before I upgraded to OSX Lion, I could open up the Bluetooth Preferences, select a device, click on the settings icon, choose 'Rename Device' and rename the Bluetooth device.

Now that I've upgraded to OSX Lion, the option is there on the same location, but it is called 'Update Name', however, it doesn't do anything for me. Is that just a dead GUI component that will get functionality tied to it later on, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8):

### System Preferences > Bluetooth

- Select (click) the device you wish to rename

[image: Choose Device and Rename]

- Click the gear icon at the bottom of the list and **Rename** is one of the actions you can take on each paired device.

[image: Renaming BT Device]

Comment: I don't have the "rename" option under the gear function button. Only the 'Update Name" option, however, like Peter, it doesn't seem to do anything. Can it be that 'rename' only works for Apple stuff (and not for logitech) and only works for connected gear?

Comment: To rename a bluetooth device it needs to be connected; that wasn't mentioned.

Comment: I believe Geert is correct; the "rename" is actually sending a new name to the device, which is a feature specific to Apple devices.

Comment: @Kevin Reid → I've renamed many third-party Bluetooth devices; where did you get that information?

Comment: Simply that I have seen "rename" available for Apple devices and not for other devices. I've just connected a non-Apple Bluetooth keyboard, and there is no option to rename (I'm running Snow Leopard). (Unfortunately, I don't have any Apple Bluetooth devices around to test with right now.)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Mavericks 10.9:

"System Preferences" - "Bluetooth" - select your device, right click - "Rename"

Answer (score 0):

J.Y Han's answer for Mavericks 10.9 no longer works with Yosemite 10.10.

Go to System Preferences -> Bluetooth.

Now, instead of right-clicking the device, hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and left-click. You will now see a menu with an option to rename the device.