# How do I change a Bluetooth device's name?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, catalina

I remember that I use to be able to change my keyboard's name in `System Preferences > Bluetooth > right-click, Rename`, but I now I only see an option to remove the keyboard.

[image]

Comment: i assume you are running Mojave?   Still works for high Sierra

Comment: @jmh Catalina (as tagged)

Comment: "instead of right-clicking the device, hold down CTRL and left-click." weird solution for Yosemite. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18144/how-to-rename-a-bluetooth-device-in-osx-lion?rq=1